# Networked simple games in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm just wondering if it's possible to do networked simple games in React Native. I heard that you could use Firebase but i think that's just for a database.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Whether or not React Native is the right tool for networked based simple games is a decision to be made by you, taking into account the mechanics of your game.

I've written a simple game, without any networking in React Native, and it performs just fine. The game is a card matching game, links below.

Now the example app i've linked shows that React Native is perfectly feasible for some small games. The question of it React Native can "do networking" OK has already been answered, i.e. you can easily integrate Web Sockets into React Native, using socket.io for example.

So in short, yes you can certainly use react native to create simple games, you can also do any necessary networking in React Native, how you setup your back-end system is outside of the scope of this question. I personally would roll my own node.js back-end, set up socket.io for the near real-time networking, and roll from there.

Android

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.memorycardpairs.www

IOS

https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1394449775